# How to set up a Laravel dev environment using Homestead, Parallels, and vagrant

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead, parallels

This is my first time setting up a dev environment other then XAMP. I have looked and tried various installs for a few days and haven't gotten anywhere.

-info
OS=Mac 10.14.1
VM= Parallels 14 ( yes I've installed the plugin)
install vagrant

All above is installed on 12/12/2018

resources I have found
https://app.vagrantup.com/laravel/boxes/homestead
https://github.com/Parallels/vagrant-parallels

I was really hoping someone could give me some help getting this set up so I can start learning Laravel!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, since you move from XAMPP and have Mac, I would recommend you trying Valet first: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/valet.
It's much easier to install and manage.

Regarding homestead, you have Parallels and Vagrant installed.

Add a Vagrant box by running command in terminal:

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

Then install Homestead:

```
git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git ~/Homestead
```

Run init script:

```
cd ~/Homestead
bash init.sh
```

Open ~/Homestead/Homestead.yaml file to adjust configurations. Be really careful with indents and signs.

Set the provider:

```
provider: parallels
```

Map the folder with website files to the virtual box:

```
folders:
    - map: ~/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code
```

Add your first website config to init nginx:

```
sites:
    - map: firstwebsite.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/firstwebsite.test/public
```

Add a record to the /etc/hosts to point domain to your virtual box

```
192.168.10.10  firstwebsite.test
```

Start the virtual box by running:

```
vagrant up
```

Try to load it: http://firstwebsite.test

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead

Comment: I also will be using Javascript(JQuery, Vue, etc) I assume that won't change anything.

Comment: If using Homestead, It'll be better to SSH into your virtual box and run npm there, because of productivity reasons.